# ASP.NET MVC: return JObject as JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm trying to return a JObject as my action resuls. I've used `Newtonsoft.Json` and [JsonNetResult](https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/1424538)  for converting objects to JsonResult.
For normal objects, I use this syntax for serializing objects into JsonResult:

```
return new JsonResult
{
    ContentType = "application/json",
    ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Data = myResult,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

Which `myResult` is instance of a desired object, However trying this for a JObject (`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`) as below, returns invalid result i.e. `[[[]]]`:

```
JObject jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject["error"] = "invalid_id";
return new JsonResult
{
    ContentType = "application/json",
    ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Data = jsonObject,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

How can I serialize JObject in this case?

Comment: You want to return a json object from an action, right?

Comment: @TânNguyễn yes and my action is going to return JsonResult as return type

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me !!

```
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, 
                 new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                     ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
        });

        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = serialized,
            ContentType = "application/json",
        };
```

response is an instance of a c# class that contains a property of type JObject.
This caused Ok(response) to *return empty array symbols **([])*** for every property inside the jobject. Manually serializing and returning it as a **contentresult** solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
    public JsonObject GetJson_1()
    {
        var errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        errors.Add("Id", "invalid");

        return new JsonObject(errors);
    }

    public ActionResult GetJson_2()
    {
        var errors = new List<object>();

        errors.Add(new { Id = "invalid" });

        return Json(errors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, OP wanted was asking specifically about JObject.